# TDD with MS Test

Tags: c#, tdd

Like all good programmers, I'm trying to get some things straight when using TDD with MS Test.  I'm following the basic Arrange, Act, Assert pattern, and something looks too complicated for my Act code.  I'm under the assumption that there should only be one action in the Act line.  So, given my sample code below, am I getting off track by first performing one action and THEN testing its condition?  Thanks for the input.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TheCountOfAllRecordsIsGreaterThanZero()
    {
        //Arrange
        var auditLog = new AuditMasterClass();

        //Act

        //Create a new record in a local list of objects
        auditLog.LogAction("MyPersonName", DateTime.Now, "Stuff", "MoreStuff",
                                   "Desc",
                                   "Comments", true, false,
                                   "UndoStatement");

        //Return the count of objects in the local list
        var count = auditLog.GetCommentCount();

        //Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(count > 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The test seems fine to me - I wouldn't be too dogmatic here but if it makes you feel better you can mark the line:  `var count = auditLog.GetCommentCount();` as part of the assertion phase ;)

One thing I would change in the test is the actual assertion - use `Assert.AreNotEqual(0, count)` or `Assert.IsTrue(count > 0, string.Format("Count was not greater than 0, it was {0}", count))` - this way you'll get a better error message in case the assertion fails.

Comment: Just to have said it: <code>Assert.AreEqual(0, count)</code> and <code>Assert.IsTrue(count > 0)</code> will produce different results. <code>Assert.GreaterThan(0, count)</code> (or however you write it with MStest) will do the trick

Comment: Unfortunately MSTest does not have GreaterThan - the only possibility is to use NotEqual or have a proper error message

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any problem with what you've done.  I would tend to inline the `count` variable and simply

```
Assert.IsTrue(auditLog.GetCommentCount() > 0);
```

but it's not significantly different.  Your test, as written, says that you are expecting when LogAction() is called with a particular set of parameters, there will be one or more comments in the log.  That's clear.  One thing I like to do is to assert the contrary of my assertion before the action, so I know that the action is really what brought about the condition.  That would, of course, be:

```
Assert.IsTrue(auditLog.GetCommentCount() == 0);
```

right before your Act.

Comment: Regarding testing that GetCommentCount() returns 0 before doing anything: Wouldn't that be more appropriate to test in another, separate test? You're supposed to test that the GetCommentCount() method returns a value greater than zero given some state S. What it returns when it is not in state S is not important in this context

Comment: @Simen, No, not at all.  Suppose GetCommentCount() returned 5 before - and after - the action.  The test as originally written would pass, but it would not actually be testing the action.  You could put ANY code - or none - that didn't affect the comment count in as the action, and the test would still pass.  The pre-action assertion is not to test how the code before it behaves, but rather to establish the baseline so the final assertion constitutes an actual change.

Comment: That's my original concern.  My test class has a few different tests: "TheReturnResultIsTrue", "TheCountOfAllRecordsIsGreaterThanZero", etc.  It seems odd for me to have to create the record in my first test before getting the count in the second test.  I'm maintaining a local list of objects in my repository, and that list gets newed up at every test, which is why I'm first adding the record and then checking its count in my second test.  Looks like I need to do a little bit o' refactoring.

Comment: @michael.lukatchik: It's not just "odd" - it's problematic.  Your tests - your *unit* tests - should be entirely independent of one another.  If test #2 requires that you add a record - add it in test #2.  If test #1 adds a record - clear it out when done (or clear all before running test #2).  Test interdependency is a nightmare; avoid it!

Comment: Yes, Carl.  I don't want test interdependency. All good points here.  I can take advantage of individual test creation and cleanup using the built in [TestInitialize()] and [TestCleanup()] methods.  Thanks!

Comment: @Carl I see your point entirely - but I dont *want* to agree - but after ~25 minutes trying to get my thoughts about this into 600 characters I give up. I'll save it for a later question/blog post!

Comment: @Simen: :-)  Please link it here so I can join the discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there usually is only one action per test case. Invoking a getter can be considered as not being an action and thus, belonging to the Assert portion of the testcase.

In the `TheCountOfAllRecordsIsGreaterThanZero` test shown above, the creation of a new record is part of the Arrange section - or the test is misnamed and could be `TheCountOfAllRecordsIncreasedUponLogAction`.

I'd also like to point out that one action per test case could means several lines of code. The idea is not a write a whole scenario with a long sequence of actions.

Comment: Good point. When I think about it, I'm really "arranging" some piece of data.  So, the creation of a new record belongs in the Arrange section.  I've learned to use the Arrange section for situations other than just newing up a single object, but you're right; the goal here is to be as lean as possible with each test.